# WebRTC Broadcast Issue on different network

Tags: webrtc, broadcast

I am new to webRtc and i dont know what to do?
I have this error. "ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details
Peer connection is closed between you & 1fw5ely6fboiksg83tj
Object { }
state: failed RTCMultiConnection.min.js:18:29996
Peer connection is closed between you & 1fw5ely6fboiksg83tj
Object { }
state: closed RTCMultiConnection.min.js:18:29996
Peer connection is closed between you & 1fw5ely6fboiksg83tj
Object { }
state: closed"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend not to use this library anymore. It's partly outdated and badly maintained. Try to find other samples or read the documentation and try it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

RTCMultiConnection is not part of the official WebRTC API. You are likely using some of Muaz Khan experiments. You have to ask the meaning of his error message on his GitHub repository.